# When can I remove my dog's bandage?

Tags: dogs, surgery

My dog recently had surgery to correct his luxating patella. Poor boy's only a year old...

The surgery was only 3 days ago and his bandage has already started to slide down his leg, exposing part of the incision and two staples.  The top edge of the tape now appears to be putting a lot of pressure right in the center of his incision and he's begun to avoid moving more than usual; I am assuming it is pretty painful. :(

Is it too soon to cut off the bandage for him? Should I wait until Monday to bring him to our vet and have them examine him then? I don't like thinking he could be in such pain for 2 days...

I do not see any oozing from the wound yet, but he has started licking at it on rare occasions (we have a Cone of Shame, but have not yet used it).

Comment: Why not call your vet and ask them? They should know the specific situation a lot better than us.

Comment: I would, except we're going into the weekend now and they're closed for 2 days...

Comment: Just call. Some can still be reached or at least provide an alternative contact/replacement. Overall I think it shouldn't be an issue, but I'd guess having the bandage sit wrong might be as bad as removing it too early, since it's both protection and support.

Answer (score 2):

If the bandage has no stabilizing effect on the joint, you could probably remove it. Either wrap a new (sanitized) bandage around the incision or put on the cone of shame. The goal is to keep the dog from removing any staples before the incision could heal. And believe me, they do try to pull them out.